# MySQL Replace not working

Tags: mysql

I have back slashes stored in mysql.

I want to remove backslash '\'. So, I run query like

```
UPDATE table_name set col_name = replace(col_name, "Equipe d\'Olivier", "Equipe d'Olivier");
```

More intrestingly, even if I query something like

```
Select * from table_name where column_name = "Equipe d\'Olivier"
```

It returns row even with `"Equipe d'Olivier"` as well

I could not get any idea on this. How can I replace or remove that backslash

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing double-quotes `"` by single-quotes `'`, and use a double back-slash. `\\`

```
UPDATE tbl 
set col_name = replace(col_name, 'Equipe d\\''Olivier', 'Equipe d''Olivier');
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=74fb2e4436732f79239c8c9269b40ab5)*